# Can I make AMQPS RabbitMQ using a Google-managed certificate on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am new to K8s. Say I want to start up a RabbitMQ in my cluster but I also want to ensure its default AMQP port is secure (AMQPS). Is it possible to do so using a GCP-managed key + certificate? If so, how? For example, I was thinking of using a LoadBalancer somehow to take care of it. Or, maybe Ingress, although it's not HTTP-based traffic (still, maybe we can work around this?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think so, all the ways you can interact with Google certs are aimed at HTTPS. You can use cert-manager with LetsEncrypt though.